# Border Layout not working?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I have a simple JLabel (response) that I want to put in the center of my JFrame, based on user interaction from a JCombobox. The JLabel response should be in the center of the window, and the JLabel selectone should be next to the combobox; currently all three are next to each other. First, I tried to use borderlayout directly with the JLabel while adding it to the JFrame, but that didn't work. Then I tried to add it while instantiating the JLabel itself, and then just adding the JLabel. Then I tried to add the JLabel to a JPanel, and adding the JPanel to the JFrame, but that didn't work either, and all three had the same result of all three next to each other. Here is my code:

```
package Buttons;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class sentencewindow extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    sentence senobj = new sentence();
    senobj.setVisible(true);
    senobj.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    senobj.setSize(500, 600);
}

}

class sentence extends JFrame {
String[] abc = { "First string", "Second String", "Third String" };
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(abc);
JLabel selectone = new JLabel("This should be next to the combobox");
JLabel response = new JLabel("This should change based on combobox selection");

sentence() {
    super("TITLE");

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    combo.addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener());
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    response.setSize(250, 250);
    container.add(response, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add (selectone);
    add(combo);

}

class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {

        if (combo.getSelectedItem().equals(abc[0])) {
            response.setText("You pressed the first option.");

        }
        if (combo.getSelectedItem().equals(abc[1])) {
            response.setText("You pressed the second option.");
        }
        if (combo.getSelectedItem().equals(abc[2])) {
            response.setText("You pressed the third option.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thank you so much for the time you are taking for reading this, I really appreciate the effort you are putting into helping a fellow programmer! I understand that this is a beginner question, but I have been stuck on it for a very long time, and have read pretty much all the questions related to this. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Is your frame supposed to have a BorderLayout? You're currently giving it a FlowLayout.

Comment: I am trying to give the JLabel itself a centered layout. I am new to layouts, but i'm pretty sure the layout of the JFrame doesn't impact the positioning and size of a JLabel within that JFrame. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Your frame AND `JPanel` are using a `BorderLayout`. Change the frame to use a `BorderLayout`, add your selections label and combo box in the panel, set this panel to the `NORTH` position, add your `response` label to the center

Comment: The layout of the JFrame controls the positioning of components within the JFrame. The layout of the JLabel would control the positioning of components within the JLabel (of which there are none, so it would be useless).

Comment: Like this:  combo.addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener());
  JPanel container = new JPanel();
  response.setSize(250, 250);
  container.add(response , BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(selectone);
  container.add(combo);
  add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);

Comment: Because that makes the response and the selectone switched. The response should be in the middle and the selectone should be next to the box. Even after switching the BorderLayout.CENTER though, it still retains its state. Please help, thanks.

Comment: And this happens only if I comment out the flow layout part

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `JLabel#setHorizontalAlignment` for centering the text in the label itself.

Add Frame with border layout, add a panel with your combobox and label to the NORTH of the frame. Add label to CENTER of frame. The label occupies the full available space and the centre text option should centre the text within the label.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work without the JLabel#setHorizontalALignment by using your other steps. How can I change the size of the text though, because changing the size of the JLabel isn't working. Also, what was the need of adding stuff to a separate panel, why couldn't I add it directly to the JFrame? I will mark best answer, and like as soon as I figure that out! Thanks.

Comment: You need a separate panel because border layout gives you only 5 places to keep your components. If you are looking to leave space before & after the label you need to add dummy components. Have a look at Box, that has some helper methods to create them.